# Is this sentence in an online dictionary correct, "They ain't got nothing to say"?

Tags: grammar

When I typed **ain't meaning** in the search bar at Google, a result from [the New Oxford American Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ain%27t) appeared with the following example:

> **They ain't got nothing to say.**

I have my doubts as to whether the use of the word **nothing** is correct or not.

Af far as my knowledge concerns, the sentence should be something like this: **They ain't got anything / something to say.**

Am I right? The word **nothing** is negative, and the word **ain't** is negative, too. We should not use two negatives, at least in this example, can we?

When they say: **They ain't got nothing to say**, it sounds like they have something to say!!

Comment: I haven't seen much eloquent prose with the word _ain't_ squeezed in. The word _ain't_ is considered informal English, and it's typically used in contexts where formal English rules are bent mightily. There's no "mistake" here; the dictionary editors ain't got nothing to worry about.

Comment: FYI Google uses Oxford Dictionaries. When you type "ain't meaning", it will return the same content as of [this link](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ain%27t).

Comment: @J.R -What about saying: They ain't got anything to say. Does it still mean the same as " They ain't got nothing to say." ? I am not obssesed with grammar! :) and I understand you saying grammar rules are bent sometimes in informal sentences.

Comment: The two sentences indeed have the same meaning; the word _ain't_ rarely negates another negative in the sentence. Maulik V explained it well in his answer by saying it's "more idiomatic than grammatical."

Comment: Double negations are a special feature of substandard language, which has its own grammar.  "They ain't got anything to say" would be  the wrong grammar in that style of language.

Comment: BTW, nothing quite often is shortened to nothin' - pronouced "nut" just like what you eat and "in" as with inside.

Answer (score 3):

This blew my mind for a while. Indeed, a very good question. This is the example of a negative concord.

> They ain't got nothing to say means *They don't have anything to say*.

I think it is **more idiomatic than grammatical.**

Along with [OxfordDictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ain%27t), such phrase is also found on some authentic sources including Google Book Result ([Behind Ghetto Walls](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=8UwY4qD9ANkC&pg=PA316&lpg=PA316&dq=%22they%20ain%27t%20got%20nothing%20to%20say%22&source=bl&ots=Udr_IJx_jA&sig=-y636BJbScponwQYVcXbzm9Fgqg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IbJkU9TfDM_HuATs_oDoBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22they%20ain%27t%20got%20nothing%20to%20say%22&f=false)).

Comment: Since *ain't* is non-standard, it's no surprise that the examples it appears in have other non-standard features such as negative concord.  It's completely grammatical in many varieties of non-standard English, but if it were standard English it would be ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3):

> They ain't got nothing to say.

This means, "They don't have anything to say."

This is **descriptively** grammatically "correct" (read "regionally or socio-politically common, understandable, and correct") usage within certain dialects and even **prescriptively correct grammar** for some entire languages which employ ["negative concord"](http://microsyntax.sites.yale.edu/negative-concord).  Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative.  It can be used as an emphasizer (instead of cancellation) or a required double negative that indicates a single negative.

Prescriptivists (such as editorial style guides) consider this "incorrect grammar" for Standard English.