# How to understand "don’t got nothing to do" grammatically and semantically

Tags: sentence-meaning, multiple-negation

> “To all y’all people asking why I would let me son ride the bus because I’m rich — being rich **don’t got nothing to do** with a child experiences,”

I saw the sentence from [here](https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/wiz-kalifa-got-dad-shamed-154916496.html). According to [this previous post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22641/is-this-sentence-in-an-online-dictionary-correct-they-aint-got-nothing-to-say) of ELL, this phenomenon has been explained as '*negative concord*' or '*double negative*', and it says in one of answers:

> ... ... It can be used as an emphasizer (instead of cancellation) or a required double negative that indicates a single negative.

So in that view, "*They ain't got nothing to say*." has been interpreted as "*They don't have anything to say*.".

By that analogy, "*being rich don’t got nothing to do with a child experiences*" should be interpreted as "*being rich **don’t have anything** to do with a child experiences*".

On the other hand, "*being rich **doesn’t** got nothing to do with a child experiences*" looks more correct to me.

How should we understand that sentence correctly? Grammatically and semantically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence can be understood as:

> "To all of you who are asking me why I would let my son ride the bus even though I'm rich, let me tell you that being rich **doesn't have anything to do** with **things that a child should experience**."

In other words, he believes that riding a bus is an important childhood experience, and one that he wants his son to have even though it's not necessary from a financial perspective. (No doubt, being rich, he could afford to have a driver take his son to school and pick him up every day.)